# What is the difference between RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial and DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I want to have an "dynamic" table ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<% foreach (var element in Model.Elements) { %>
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => element) %>
<% } %>
```

with model:

```
public class TableViewModel<ElementType> {
     public List<ElementType> Elements {get;set;}
}
```

1. first strangely enough I cannot write something like this in ascx directives:
   `<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl>" %>`
2. then the second problem - I cannot use DisplayFor function extension, because compiler cannot deduce HtmlHelper<> generic param, because the ascx model is dynamic. That is why I had to replace the:
   `<%= Html.DisplayFor(m => element) %>`
   with the:
   `<% RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(Html, "Table", element); %>`

So my questions are am I doing something wrong, or if I'm not what is the difference between DisplayFor and RenderPartial in terms of performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try to use just Display?

RenderPartial just renders partial view. DisplayFor uses UIHint or DisplayTemplate from Shared views for rendering.

Comment: I know that but can anybody tell me is there some performance penalty using one or the other?

Comment: I think it exists, but not very big. When you call RenderPartial of course it works quicker,because it dont need to use much Reflection logic as DisplayFor do. BUT using DisplayFor is much easier and clearer to understand (it's ASP.NET MVC recommended way) and perfomance delta is not big.